# Is it possible to get AEC model data fofr a IFC4 file with Forge model derivative APIs?

Tags: forge, autodesk-bim360, ifc

I am trying to read simple AEC data such as Level and components etc,
I came across .rvt files supports extraction AEC data as explained here :https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api,
I am trying to achieve similar results with IFC files any idea if its possible,
Or if there is another better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Forge translation does not generate AEC data when translating an IFC file.

There is a reason for this: Forge IFC translation goes via NavisWorks, not Revit.

Just like Forge itself, NavisWorks is a generic model vieer, and not AEC specific.

Therefore, AEC specific data is not generated or extracted from the models it processes.

One option to handle your requirement would be to use Forge Design Automation to launch Revit, import the IFC file, and then generate the required AEC specific information there.

Comment: interestingly, I was able to view AEC data for IFC files in Bim360 docs viewer which is also a Forge viewer,  when i tried 'NOP_VIEWER.model.getDocumentNode().getAecModelData()" on console, Just curious ,How different Bim360's viewer with respect to regular Forge viewer which we are using in our apps?